# Cannot resolve symbol 'onCompleteListener'

Tags: android-studio

I followed this tutorial https://morioh.com/p/10dc2d87bb2f but despite doing everything the same i get the following error:

error: cannot find symbol
mAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener( MainActivity.his,new onCompleteListener() {
^
symbol:   variable his
location: class MainActivity

I tried changing the cersions of play-services and firebase-auth/core but nothing changed.

My MainActivity.java:

```
package com.imoroney.easylearn;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SignInButton signInButton;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoodleSignInClient;
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button btnSignOut;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        btnSignOut = findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestEmail().build();

        mGoodleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                signIn();
            }
        });

        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGoodleSignInClient.signOut();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Signed Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn(){
        Intent signInIntent = mGoodleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask){
        try {

            GoogleSignInAccount acc = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signed In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseGoogleAuth(acc);
        }
        catch (ApiException e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign In Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseGoogleAuth(null);

        }

    }

    private void FirebaseGoogleAuth(GoogleSignInAccount acct){
        AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(),null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener( MainActivity.his,new onCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser fUser){
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
        if(account != null){
            String personName = account.getDisplayName();
            String personGivenName = account.getGivenName();
            String personFamilyName = account.getFamilyName();
            String personEmail = account.getEmail();
            String personId = account.getId();
            Uri personPhoto = account.getPhotoUrl();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, personName + personEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.imoroney.easylearn"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'

}
```